# Hidden Youtube video ID

Tags: javascript, youtube, jwplayer

I need to hidden the video ID of an Youtube video. I need to "private" my video on my website (requires login). I know that is impossible avoid that someone get the real URL, but I need make it better than possible.

Currently I set my video as "not listed". But when I set this video on my JWPlayer it show the Youtube logo (that is not the problem) but with a Video URL on click (it is the problem!).

So, how I can make hard to discovery the Video ID/URL on my page?

Bye!

Comment: You are obviously not new to SO, you know how to research and ask relevant questions, so research!

Comment: Yes... I found some answers, but not solve totally my problem. @Sparrowhawk solve it, without solve. :D I can't do that, so. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible, and is in fact against Youtube's TOS.  Sorry!

See http://www.youtube.com/t/terms (section 5G)

*"if you use the YouTube Player on your website may not modify, build upon or block any portion or functionality of the YouTube Player including but not limited to links back to the Website"*

Comment: Um, no, there is no 4F... It's actually 5.1G ;)

Comment: Hmm, it seems to be different in different countries, my mistake.  Oh well it says the same thing in any case, heh.

Comment: Turn off direct link (?v=...) is against TOS too? I say, accept Youtube logo, but redirect to Youtube, instead of redirect to my video page?